# C2678 being thrown for no apparent reason to me

Tags: list, exception, visual-c++, operator-keyword

I am trying to compile this project just to see how I am doing as I go along, but I still have a few more classes to implement that will inherit from Widget for different types. When I compile I keep getting C2678:

> Error C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand
>   operand of type 'Widget' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
>   Assignment10  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\xutility  line3107

I cant find where this error is thrown or why. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry it's so sloppy, I've been messing with it a lot to try and find the problem.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Widget
{
public:


    int idNumber;
    //structors
    Widget()
    { 
        idNumber = 0;
    }
    Widget(int a) 
    { 
        idNumber = a;
    }
    ~Widget();

    //operations
    int getId() 
    {
        return idNumber;
    }
    //overload operators to compare idNumber
    void operator= (Widget &rhs)
    {
        idNumber = rhs.idNumber;
    }
};

----------------------------------------
#include "Widget.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Widget::~Widget()
{
}

/*


bool Widget::operator< (Widget &rhs)
{
    bool result;
    result = idNumber < rhs.idNumber;
    return result;
}*/

---------------------------------
#pragma once
#include "Widget.h"
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Inventory
{
public:
    Inventory();
    Inventory(int i)
    {
        Widget w(i);
    }
    ~Inventory();



    //operations
    //process order for shipment
    void order(int widgID);
    //recieve widget 
    void receive(int widgID);

    //overlaod output operator
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Widget&);

protected: 
    list<Widget> onHand;
    list<int> onOrder;
};

-------------------------------
#include "Inventory.h"
#include "Widget.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;


Inventory::Inventory()
{
    Widget w;
}

Inventory::~Inventory()
{
}

//recieve widget 
void Inventory::receive(int widgID)
{
    cout << " Recieved shipment of Widget type "
        << widgID << endl;

    //find the iterator of the widget location
    list<int>::iterator weNeed;
    weNeed = find(onOrder.begin(), onOrder.end(), widgID);

    //if end is returned, item not found
    if (weNeed != onOrder.end())
    {
        cout << "Ship " << Widget(widgID) << " to fill back order" << endl;
        onOrder.erase(weNeed);

    }
    else
    {
        onHand.push_front(Widget(widgID));
    }
}

//process order
void Inventory::order(int widgID)
{
    cout << " Recieved order for Widget type "
        << widgID << endl;

    //find the iterator of the widget location
    list<Widget>::iterator weHave;
    weHave = find(onHand.begin(), onHand.end(), widgID);    


    //if end is returned, item not found
    if (weHave != onHand.end())
    {
        cout << "Ship " << *weHave <<  endl;
        onHand.erase(weHave);

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Back order widget of type "
            << widgID << endl;
        onHand.push_front(Widget(widgID));
    }
}



ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Widget& wid)
{
    os << wid.idNumber;
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Look in the Output window for expanded template compile error messages.

Comment: How do you expect `find(onHand.begin(), onHand.end(), widgID)` to work when there's no mechanism to compare a `Widget` with a `widgID`? This is what the error is telling you.

Comment: ok thanks, didnt have to be rude about it.. a friend helped me with it.